# CAD annotation guide lines do not show in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, annotation, autocad

When I open a CAD file in Arcmap the annotation's guid lines and arrows linking to feature do not appear. see snapshots below.
how can I show thses guides in armap?

[image: dwg in autocad]

[image: dwg in arcmap]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ran into this as well. Annotations (they're called dimensions actually) are not read by ArcGIS. The only workaround I've found is to import the CAD data into a GDB using Data Interoperability.

Comment: thnak you for this information.
did this show the "dimensions" on ArcGIS?

Comment: Once they're imported as gdb feature classes, yes. ArcGIS still can't read them in the original CAD file. I've had to test different import options to make this work though, the default options of the Quick Import tool were not adapted. If this method is suitable for you and if you need more help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explode the required guidlines in the CAD if ArcGIS cannot read them. make sure to only explode required guidelines (dimensions) without other features so they can be distinguishable by the software.

in AutoCAD first lock all other layers, 
 use the command 'EXPLODE', 
 then use'REGEN',
 and save before opening in ArcGIS.